# What is this C++ function doing behind the obfuscated syntax?

Tags: c++

What operation is implemented here ?

```
   char char_func(char **str) {
      char c; 
      return ((c=*((*str)++))?c:*(--(*str)));
    }
```

**EDIT** It is taken from C++ examination test. It is not supposed to help anyone or solve any problem. Just looking for an explanation behind the obfuscated syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same as:

```
char char_func(char** ptr)
{
    char c = **ptr;       // read the current character (pointed by ptr)
    (*ptr)++;             // move the original pointer (ptr) to next character
    if (c != '\0')        // if the character in c is not the one ending the sequence
    {
        return c;         // return that character
    }
    else                  // otherwise
    {
        --(*ptr);         // move the original pointer back one step (back to '\0')
        return **ptr;     // return that last '\0' character
    }
}
```

which means that **each subsequent call** returns the **next character** of the string (characters' sequence) passed as an argument until character `\0` is encountered (then it repeatedly returns that `\0` character):

```
int main()
{
    char tab[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };

    char* ptr = tab;                     

    printf("%c ", char_func(&ptr));      //  a  b  c  \0
                                         //  ^  
    printf("%c ", char_func(&ptr));      //  a  b  c  \0
                                         //     ^  
    printf("%c ", char_func(&ptr));      //  a  b  c  \0
                                         //        ^   
    printf("%c ", char_func(&ptr));      //  a  b  c  \0
                                         //            ^
    printf("%c ", char_func(&ptr));      //  a  b  c  \0
                                         //            ^       ^=ptr
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a b c \0 \0
```

Answer (score 2):

If `*str` isn't zero, it will return `**str` and increment `*str`.
Otherwise, it resets the increment and returns `**str` (which will be zero in that case).

That is, you can use it to pop off the front of `*str` until you reach zero.

Rewriting the function to be less obfuscated:

```
char char_func(char **str) {
   char c = str[0][0];
   if (c)
      str[0] += 1;
   return c;
}
```

Example: the following program prints "Hello, world!" one character at a time.

```
#include <iostream>

char char_func(char **str) {
   char c; 
   return ((c=*((*str)++))?c:*(--(*str)));
}

int main() {

   char test[] = "Hello, world!";
   char* t = test;
   for (char c = char_func(&t); c; c = char_func(&t))
      std::cout << c;
}
```